# Python3.x - How to stop python script from closing after encountering an error (without using a batch file)

Tags: python-3.x

I tried running a python script, but it immediately closes when it encounters an error. Is there a way to stop the console window from closing after an error without using a batch file and without typing this command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K <command>
```

By the way, adding `try` and `except` still doesn't stop the console window from closing. Even using:

```
except:
  sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the console closes as soon as the python program is finished.  So if you `sys.exit(0)` in your `except` statement, the program finishes and the console close.

Either you write a `.bat` file next to your python file, that makes sure to call `cmd.exe` properly, and you run that one.  Or you wait in the `except` statement for some user input/confirmation and `sys.exit()` only then.

Last solution if you want to see the console only to see the messages, try to print the messages to a file, either using `print( "abc", file=opened_file )` in the python code, or adding `> filename` at the end of the shell command to redirect the standard output to a file.

Personally, I just run the program directly from `cmd.exe`'s shell and never close the terminal.